# Ways to measure the focal length of a convex lens with only natural sun light

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, home-experiment, geometric-optics, lenses

What are the common ways to measure the focal length of a convex lens with only natural sun light?

Comment: If I said 42, would you believe me? Seriously - you might want to rephrase the question a little bit... "how many" is a question that requires a numerical answer; I suspect you would like instead a list with different ways to measure the focal length.

Comment: How about $e^\pi$?

Comment: It's not common, at all, to measure the focal length of lenses with sunlight. The "common" way to measure a focal length is by using a dioptometer, which is far more convenient and precise.

Comment: This seems like a list-type question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows [insufficient willingness to get off your butt](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 4):

Given that you use the tag "home-experiment" I will give an answer in that spirit.

Obviously you can use the convex lens to focus the sunlight onto a piece of paper - find the distance where the paper catches fire and that is your focal length. That's how I did it when I was 4. Shoe laces too - they are really stinky when you get the distance right. Wear sunglasses while you do this - looking at the focused image of the sun is brutal on your eyes.

You can also use the lens in a crude camera - a box with a pair of cardboard tubes that allow you to slide the lens in and out, and tracing paper at the back. Now point at a distant well (sun) lit object, and "focus". Measure the distance. You could even repeat for different distances and see whether the lensmakers formula holds:

$$\frac{1}{f}=\frac{1}{d}+\frac{1}{\ell}$$

$f$=focal length, $d$ = object distance, $\ell$ = distance from lens to focal plan.

This has the advantage that you have multiple measurements and can fit a straight line by plotting $\frac{1}{\ell}$ as a function of $\frac{1}{d}$, with the intersection with the Y axis corresponding to "infinity" ($\frac{1}{\infty}=0$).